# Quadrisecants of rational space curves via degeneration

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $C \subset \mathbf P^3$ be a smooth rational curve of degree $d$. Cayley proved in 1863 that the number of quadrisecants to such a curve (if it is finite) is given by the formula

$$\frac{1}{12}(d-2)(d-3)^2(d-4). $$
There are various ways to prove this. My question is about a specific approach to proving this, via degeneration.

So now assume that $C$ degenerates to a chain of lines $C_0 \subset \mathbf P^3$. That is, $C_0=L_1 \cup \cdots \cup L_d$ where each $L_i$ is a line, $L_i$ intersects $L_j$ if $|i-j|=1$, and $L_i$ and $L_j$ are disjoint otherwise.

I would like to know whether we can prove Cayley's formula (correctly!) by using $C_0$.

There is an old paper of Wong, ["Enumerative properties of $r$-space curves"](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1934-40-04/S0002-9904-1934-05854-3/S0002-9904-1934-05854-3.pdf) that attempts to obtain the formula in this way.

Naively one might say that given 4 general lines in $\mathbf P^3$, there are 2 lines intersecting all 4, and so we get $2 \cdot {d \choose 4} = \frac{1}{12}d(d-1)(d-2)(d-3)$ quadrisecants. This number exceeds the correct answer by $(d-2){d-2 \choose 2}$.

Wong's explanation of the correction is as follows (p. 295):

> Any four general skew lines have two transversals. If they intersect in pairs or if two of them intersect only, there is only one transversal.

To make sense of the statement above, it seems that "transversal" must be interpreted as a line intersecting all 4 given lines but not containing any intersection point of 2 of the lines. If so, it is not clear to me how to prove that only these lines should be included in the count.

So my question is as follows:

**Question:** Is there a rigorous specialisation argument that computes the number of quadrisecants of $C$ by counting quadrisecants of $C_0$?